# Error using PHP Users API on Google App Engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I have a PHP app running on Google App Engine, and I'm trying to use the users API to restrict this to users within my Google Apps domain. I've set this up in the application settings, and written code to do the checking. Using the local dev server it all works fine (I get the login prompt, and can login and logout just fine), but when I deploy it to production it dies with this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'google\appengine\api\users\UsersException' with message 'Action not allowed.' in  /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/api/users/UserService.php:158

when I try and call:

```
UserService::createLoginUrl('/');
```

I'm not really sure how to debug this further. Is there another step I need to take to get this working in production?

Comment: Did you configure your app to use OpenID or restrict access to a Google Apps Domain?

Comment: Yes, it's configured to be restricted to my Google Apps domain.

Comment: In that case we already ensure users are logged in before they can even access the site, so no need to create a login URL.